# Flyway migrations needing superuser privilege

Tags: flyway

I have some flyway migrations that need DB superuser privilege to get executed. I want to avoid running the flyway migrations as a superuser and run the app say a different less privileged user (I can not run the app as a superuser).

Is there any good way to achieve this with flyway, i.e. have different migrations run as different users?

Comment: Could you run flyway as superuser/admin and then grant privileges to the appuser?

Comment: I think I will have to grant superuser privilege to the appuser, in which case I might as well run flyway as that user. Doesnt look like there is any way to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two Flyway migrations runs (regular & superuser), however this could then set you up for trouble as you would have to be very careful with their interdependencies.

The best solution is the one you already mentioned: configure Flyway with a user that has the necessary privileges. Simple and easy.